# How to get half of width with FlexBox

Tags: html, css

I have 2 solutions: the first is to add a new `div.cell` to the second`div.row` or use calc. Maybe there is another way to do this.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.cell:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">cell 1.1</div>
  <div class="cell">cell 1.2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell" style="flex: 0.5">cell 1.2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more, what is your question? What is the expected result/output?

Comment: Half of the width is 50%.

Comment: So what's wrong with the current implementation? What do you want to achieve? If we don't know what you're asking we're unable to answer your question (except with a lot of guesses), which makes your question either 'unclear what you're asking' or 'too broad,' either of which are reasons to close your question which we'd rather not do, if we can possibly help instead.

Comment: margin-right: 10px; is causing the difference for last row add that to ths style of last row or to the .cell class directly to look equal width - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GRKrPXO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use calc() to set width minus the margin in action .

```css
  .row {
  display: flex;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.cell:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.cell:first-child:last-child {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  flex:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">cell 1.1</div>
  <div class="cell">cell 1.2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">cell 1.1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The straight forward way is to use flex: 0 0 50%;

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">cell 1.1</div>
  <div class="cell">cell 1.2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">cell 1.2</div>
</div>
```